# why am i getting an error that reads "subscript requires array or pointer type" I am trying to read my array to see if its an operand

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack

This code is supposed to read postfix problems from a file and and write the answers to a new file; my error is in the if else if section of the code. I tried to move the character array to the top and it still persists.

```
 void main()
    {
    ifstream postin("postfix.txt");
    ofstream postout("postfixAnswers.txt");
        char oper = 'c';
        int i = 0;
        double number = 0;

        while(oper != '$')
        {

            while(oper != '\n'|| oper != '$')
            {
                stack operands;

                while(oper != ' ' || oper != '\n' || oper != '$')
                {
                    char a[90]; 
                    i=0;
                    oper = postin.get();
                        do
                        {
                            if(oper!=' ')
                            {
                                a[i]= oper;
                                i++;
                                oper = postin.get();
                            }
                        }while(oper != ' ' && oper != '\n');

                    if(isOperand(a))
                    {
                        double number = atof(a);
                        operands.Push(number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        operands.Pop(number);
                        double b = number; 
                        operands.Pop(number);
                        double a = number;
                        if(a[0] == '+')
                        {
                            operands.Push(a+b);
                        }
                        else if(a[0] == '-')
                        {
                            operands.Push(a-b);
                        }
                        //DIV by ZERO exception
                        else if(a[0] == '/')
                        {
                            operands.Push(a/b);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            operands.Push(a*b);
                        }
                    }
                }
                operands.Pop(number);
                postout << number<< endl;
                operands.~stack();
            }
        }



    postin.close();
    postout.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
                    double a = number;
                    if(a[0] == '+')
```

Your variable `a` is a `double`. It looks like you have declared two variables `a` with the same name, one of type `char[90]` and the other of type `double`. Use distinct variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You've redefined `a` as a `double`. In the `if` statement, `a` refers to the `double` and not the `char` array that you defined earlier.

```
  double a = number;
  if(a[0] == '+')
```